# std::move do not creating derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, move-constructor

I have container which contains shared_ptr to base class `Base` in `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> >` vec, also this container has function `add(Base&& base)` - which adding base object to vec by using `std::move` operator, but Derived move constructor does not call, only base move constructor called.

How to fix: I should convert it to Derived by using `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&base)` and after that use `std::move`.

Question: Do I need try cast to all possible derived classes and after that use `std::move`?

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}

    Base(const Base& base) = delete;
    Base(Base&& base){
        std::cout<<"base move\n";
    }
    Base(){}

    virtual void func(){
        std::cout<<"run func from BASE class\n";
    }
};
class Derived: public Base{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() = default;
    Derived(Derived&& derived):Base(std::move(derived)){
        std::cout<<"Derived move\n";
    }
    Derived():Base(){

    }

    virtual void func() override {
        std::cout<<"run func from DERIVED class\n";
    }
};
class Container{
    std::vector<shared_ptr<Base> > vec;
public:
    void add(Base&& base){
        this->vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Base>(std::move(base)));
    }
    void addDerived(Base&& base){
        //TRY ALL POSSIBLE CASTING???
        this->vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived>(std::move( *(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&base)) )));
    }

    void print(){
        for(auto& obj: vec){
            obj->func();
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    std::cout << "Create container and add using function `add`" << std::endl;
    Container container;
    container.add(Derived());
    container.print();

    std::cout << "Create container and add using function `addDerived`" << std::endl;
    Container container_new;
    container_new.addDerived(Derived());
    container_new.print();
}
//Will print
Create container and add using function `add`
base move
run func from BASE class
Create container and add using function `addDerived`
base move
Derived move
run func from DERIVED class
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad interface:

```
void add(Base&& base){
    this->vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Base>(std::move(base)));
}
```

You're just always creating a `Base`. You're slicing off the base subobject, this isn't a true polymorphic copy. In order to do that, you'd have to add something like a `clone()` method on `Base`.

But it's simpler to just leave the polymorphism to the user. Your job is just to provide a safe interface. That interface should be:

```
void add(std::shared_ptr<Base> p) {
    vec.push_back(std::move(p));
}
```

Now I, as the user, can provide a `shared_ptr` to whatever derived type I want, without you as the interface designer needing to worry about it:

```
container.add(std::make_shared<MySuperCoolDerived>(42)); // cool
```

Comment: Thanks! But in the current context, I cannot pass shared_ptr from the interface. I pass values to vector inside my constructor, where input argument is initializer_list. Check please my update!

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class D>
std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<std::decay_t<D>*, Base*>::value >
add(D&& d){
  add(std::make_shared<std::decay_t<D>>(std::forward<D>(d)));
}
void add(std::shared_ptr<Base> base){
  this->vec.push_back(std::move(base));
}
template<class D, class...Args>
void emplace(Args&&...args){
  add(std::make_shared<D>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

there are now 3 ways to add something.

`add(Derives())` works like you want it to.  `add(std::make_shared<Foo>(7))` lets you inject shared ptrs directly.

And `emplace<Derived>(args...)` lets you construct it in place.

The add has a fancy SFINAE check; I skipped it for emplace.  You could do the same converible check, and add is constructible if D from Args...  Also, when I write emplace, I sometimes add first-argument is initializer list contructor, as that fixes a common imperfection of perfect forwarding.

Comment: Thanks, the method `add` works perfectly! Template has done its work. But can you check my update about initializer_list inside constructor.

Comment: @AlfredHichkog If you have a new question, use the question button not the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop trying to move into the object to begin with. If you want to have a container of pointers to some base class, but you don't want the user to directly allocate the derived classes that you store, then it should be up to your insertion function to do the allocation. In which case, it should work like the typical standard library `emplace` functions:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void add(Args && ...args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "The type must be a base class of `Base`");
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T&, Base&>::value, "The type must be an *accessible* base class of `Base`");
    this->vec.push_back(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

...

container.add<Derived>();
```

If the user has a `Derived` instances that they want to move into a new `Derived` created by the `container`, then they would do `container.add<Derived>(std::move(theirDerivedInstance));`.

Comment: This is one of the things I find weird about the standard library. `is_base_of` often seems like the wrong thing, since it'll match private/ambiguous bases too... and what you probably want is `is_convertible<T*, Base*>`, which doesn't convey the intent at all...

Comment: @Barry: You need both, since something can be convertible without actually being a base of it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not if you do the check on the pointer rather than the reference.

Comment: @T.C.: Fair enough, but this way, you get to more directly diagnose the problem for the user. You can tell the difference between the user not making it a base class, and the user not making it an accessible base class.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe there needs to be `std::is_public_base_of`. Though now that I write it, that looks terrible. And even public is insufficient. Blegh.

Comment: Thanks, it works good!
Check please my update about initilizer_list as input argument :)